# How to get the value in a ngFor listofLog Angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm newbie about Angular so I need to pass value from component to another in a with a ngFor. Suppose to have two components: logs and log.
my `logs.component.html` is:

```
//iterane on a list that I have created 
    <app-log *ngFor="let log of listLog;let i= index"></app-log>
```

in my log.component.html:

```
//Something like this
<p>The server timestamp {{ log[i] }}</p>
```

How is it possible pass log value in the log.component.html and how I cna print it?

Comment: When you iterate, log already represents an element of your array listLog. so inside the ngFor, you jyou can use `{{ log }}` if it's a string or `{{ log | json }}` if it's an object to see what happens. I don't understand what you are trying to do without seeing what is the structure of your log elements.

Comment: Do you want to instantiate an "app-log" component for each log in the list listLog ? Then you can  add it to the attributes of app-log, and wrap the app-log in `<ng-container>`, and use the*ngFor in the ng-container. (edit: see posted answer from Anuradha Gunasekara for the details of this suggestion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this.

**parent-component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let log of listLog">
  <app-log [log]="log"></app-log>
</ng-container>
```

**app-log.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-log',
  styleUrls: ['./app-log.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './app-log.component.html'
})

export class LogComponent {

  @Input()
  public log: any; // change any to the data type of log

}
```

**app-log.html**

```
<div>
  {{log}}
</div>
```

Comment: This is correct. You don't need to mention 'let i = index' though in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you try to do that :

Parent component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { HEROES } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-parent',
  template: `
    <h2>{{master}} controls {{heroes.length}} heroes</h2>
    <app-hero-child *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
      [hero]="hero"
      [master]="master">
    </app-hero-child>
  `
})
export class HeroParentComponent {
  heroes = HEROES;
  master = 'Master';
}
```

Child component :

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-child',
  template: `
    <h3>{{hero.name}} says:</h3>
    <p>I, {{hero.name}}, am at your service, {{masterName}}.</p>
  `
})
export class HeroChildComponent {
  @Input() hero: Hero;
  @Input('master') masterName: string;
}
```

You have all the explanations on the Angular documentation here :
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding